# how to rearrange duplicate sql data into additional column

Tags: sql

I have data like this:

```
|   ID    |    phoneno    
|   01    |    0110111    
|   01    |    0110112    
|   02    |    0220222    
|   03    |    0330333    
|   03    |    0330334
```

I'd like to arrange them to:

```
|   ID    |    phoneno1    |   phoneno2  |  phoneno3  
|   01    |    0110111     |  0110112                
|   02    |    0220222     
|   03    |    0330333     |  0330334
```

is that possible with a single SQL statement? Thanks

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag your backend but this would still work with many backends:

```
with tmp (id, rowNo, PhoneNo) as 
( 
    select id, row_number() over (partition by id order by phoneno), phoneno
    from myPhones
)
select id,
  max(case when rowno = 1 then phoneNo end) phoneNo1,
  max(case when rowno = 2 then phoneNo end) phoneNo2,
  max(case when rowno = 3 then phoneNo end) phoneNo3
from tmp
group by id;
```

and here is a [DbFiddle link for demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=73262a7825d1d49c8498ae3ff556057f)

PS: Depending on your backend your database might have built-in or extension functions for this (ie: table_func in postgreSQL, pivot in MS SQL server ..._). You might search for pivot or crosstab.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively , you can show them all in one column as csv:

```
 select id,string_agg(phoneno, ',') phonenumbers
 from myPhones
 group by id
 order by id;
```

| id | phonenumbers |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 0110111,0110112 |
| 02 | 0220222 |
| 03 | 0330333,0330334 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=51e32867b88dfd4be0dfbfdfbe8fd17e)*

Comment: hmm ok, will think about how i can make that one usable with my coding. Thank you!